# How to give a form parameter a name in rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with several radio buttons. The parameter it submits is an array of hashes. In the server logs, the array of hashes doesn't seem to have a name (probably because I need to give it one). Consequently, I can't tell `params.require(:availability).permit(:<HERE>)` to permit it, since I don't know what name to put inside `.permit()`.

I've tried tinkering with the private controller method do relax requirements there, but I figure that's a hack rather than a good solution.

Here is my code in the view that generates the array of hashes

```
<%= form_tag("/availabilities/") do |f| %> 
<%= label_tag :availability %>
<% @hours.each do |hour| %>  
<%= hour[:time_slot] %>
<%= radio_button_tag hour.to_s, available_in_words(hour[:time_slot_available?]) %>
<%= radio_button_tag hour.to_s, available_in_words(!hour[:time_slot_available?]) %></br>
<% end %> <!-- ends hour loop --> 

<div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
<% end %> <!-- ends form -->
```

Note: what is being submitted via this form **doesn't** match the fields in the `Availability` model - it's more raw and will need work after submission before creating/updating records in Availability. I'm not sure if that affects things

#### What I know so far

I thought `label_tag` would give the form parameter a name by which it could be referenced in `params.require(:availability)` but that leads to error `param is missing or the value is empty: availability`

#### Note

This is what `params` looks like after submission:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"KEuNcLzuAcQj6b+0oQ0FzjOE35f1Xq3MNNomzTnC9SCML9kaWVIFgphCgDRy5cHowxQ/N4kodNIXYCAwtCPGnA==", "{:time_slot=>2020-08-22 18:00:00 +1000, :time_slot_available?=>false}"=>"Unavailable", "{:time_slot=>2020-08-22 20:00:00 +1000, :time_slot_available?=>false}"=>"Available", "commit"=>"Save", "controller"=>"availabilities", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

Accessing "authenticity_token" is easy enough: `params[:authenticity_token]`. But I can't meaningfully access the input from the radio buttons

Comment: @jvillian yes I did. Whenever I finish this app (perhaps 2027), it will be 90% your responses on stack overflow with some comments from me joining it all together :)

Comment: @jvillian basically, when I submit the array, it goes through (can see it in the logs), but it doesn't have a name, so I can't "grab" it in the create action of the controller

Comment: @jvillian I've looked at how to access a param by index (I don't think there's a way), and apparently treating a set of params like a hash is frowned upon, so I tinkered there but moved on from that approach

Comment: The `radio_button_tag` method is behaving as specified in the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag). I suggest you add to your question your *desired* params and then we can work backwards from there.

Comment: Thanks @jvillian I can definitely do that. TBH I'll be very happy with being able to access the array of hashes in any way (best practice preferably, but there may not be a rails way for this). Basically I'm after some data structure that holds info about true/false for each time slot (user submits them all at once through the form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is the first parameter to almost all the FormTagHelper methods.

> ```
> radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})
> ```
>
> https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag

In Rack (which Rails sits on top of) you can pass hashes through the parameters by using brackets:

```
foo[bar][a]=1&foo[bar][b]=2
```

Will result in:

```
{
  foo: {
    bar: {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    }
  }
}
```

You can whitelist nested hashes by passing a hash to .permit:

```
params.require(:foo).permit(bar: [:a, :b])
```

You can pass arrays through the parameters by using empty brackets:

```
foo[bar][]=1&foo[bar][]=2
```

Which will result in:

```
{
   foo: {
     bar: [1,2]
   }
}
```

You can then whitelist an array by:

```
params.require(:foo).permit(bar: [])
```

`[]` will allow an array of [permitted scalar values](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).

I'm not sure exactly what `@hour.to_s` returns but you might need to ensure that it is something actually suited to be used as a key in a formdata key/value pair and does not mess with Rack's parameter parser.

Comment: Such a comprehensive answer! @hour.to_s returns seconds from 1 Jan 1970 as a string (had to name it something and that seemed informative and not too verbose)

Comment: Yeah that would be really hard to whitelist as it will just creates a bunch of "root" keys which you can't know the keys of beforehand.

Comment: I'd been grappling with that and figured so much. My next idea was to simply `params` (rather than strong parameters, which I don't know enough about and therefore won't use). So what I'm currently exploring/attempting is using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` *and* multiple records for the same model. I dare say there'll be a question about it on SO later this evening.

Comment: You can put them in a hash with `"radio_button_tag(hours[#{@hour}]", ...` and then use `params[:hours].permit!` when extracting the parameters to allow the entire hash.